# How to call a method from my panel class through the button-actionPerformed in the dialog-class, that get´s it´s instance in the panel-class?

Tags: java

I have a frame-class, that creates an instance of a panel-class.
and the panel-class creates an instance of a dialog class.

In the dielog class i have this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
    panel.changeLevel((int)levelList.getSelectedItem());

    setVisible(false);
}
```

How must i start the method-call to use the method of the already existing instance of panel, that is created in the frame-class (not create a new instance)?

i want to sent a number back to the instance of panel, that has called the dialog box, and use it there to run a method

Comment: perhaps try a evt.getSource()?

Comment: i think, that returns the button, because it´s the event, that runs ba clickeng the button on the dialog

Comment: What class contains the `actionPerformed()` method? Can you show this **as code** rather than in words?

Answer (score 3):

Since your actionPerformed method is in the dialog class, I'm assuming that you are using the dialog class as your listener.

If you make a controller class OR set the panel class to be your listener, you can place the ActionPerformed event in the controller/panel class, which will then have access to the methods/fields that it needs to be able to reach

(Using the panel is the easiest fix, using a controller or a custom listener class is the better design).

Comment: as i added the actionlistener to my panel class, It wotks, but at starting the project, an error appears in the console and disappears, bevor i can read it.

Comment: There's no way for us to know what that error is or how to fix it without either you posting your code here or telling us what the error is.

Comment: i found out, that the error was just garbage from an older run, that was not fully closed and stayed there in the background of the console. now i closed all stuff in the console and no more errors appear.